# How to add subdomain using .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, hosting

my website is www.quotestore.tk . Its done using php.
Please provide me a code in .htaccess that can create subdomain.

I need a sub domain like sms.quotestore.tk. It will redirect to any other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do this from your .htaccess file. You need to fix this in your web server by using for example att separate virtual host.

Comment: Can i get an example code for my website www.quotestore.tk.
Subdomain required :sms.quotestore.tk

Comment: It depends on where you host your domain. Is it possible for you to add virtual hosts there?

Comment: Did you meant adding virtual host using .htaccess??

Comment: 1. Your domains are pointed to an ip address in the dns server you are using.  Both the www. and the sms.

Comment: I am using tk domain. Is there any way to do it from their side

Comment: 2. The ip address leads to a server. If  both domains lead to the same server that server needs to be able to handle virtual hosts or similar so that the two domains can be handled separately. The answer depends on what webserver you are using.

Comment: Your domain is probably bought from a registrar that handles .tk domains. It is possible that the registrar handles the hosting of the domain. You should probably turn to the them for help with this.